# Telegram Bot API send Photo returns Error code 400

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

i am using [Telegram Bot Api Library](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot) , and there is a problem with sending photos. using code below returns me a Error:

> (Telegram.Bot.Types.ApiRequestException A Telegram.Bot.Types.ApiRequestException was caught: "[Error]: Photo has unsupported extension. Use one of .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png, .tif or .bmp"has unsupported extension. Use one of .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png, .tif or .bmp".

but i am sure that my photo extension is correct and `api.GetMe()` is working fine.

```
   using (var stream = File.Open("1.jpg", FileMode.Open))
       {
    var rep = await Bot.SendPhoto(update.Message.Chat.Id, new FileToSend("name", stream));
                         }
```

whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `FileToSend("name", stream)`, you need to use `FileToSend("name.jpg", stream)`.

Comment: i found the solution name.jpg is wrong i should put 1.jpg , please edit your answer